# Android Studio could not execute method for android: onClick

Tags: java, android, xml, fatal-error

hi I am the second android programing and I encounter a problem :

[image]

and my xml files

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webViewharita"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/layoutCizimAraclariYan" >
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnNavigatorYan"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:background="@drawable/aapan_a"
                 android:visibility="invisible"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir" />
             
             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnNoktaYan"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnNavigatorYan"
                 android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/aanokta"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"
                 android:paddingLeft="1dp" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnCizgiYan"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnNoktaYan"
                 android:background="@drawable/aacizgi"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"/>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnAlanYan"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnCizgiYan"
                 android:background="@drawable/aaalan"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"/>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnDuzenleYan"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAlanYan"
                 android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/aaduzenle"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"/>
             
             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnSecYan"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDuzenleYan"
                 android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/aasec"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"/>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnKaydirYan"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSecYan"
                 android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/aakaydir"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/layoutCizimAraclari" >
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnNavigator"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:background="@drawable/aapan_a"
                 android:visibility="visible"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir" />
             
             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnNokta"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/btnNavigator"
                 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/aanokta"
                 android:visibility="visible"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"
                 android:paddingLeft="1dp" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnCizgi"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/btnNokta"
                 android:background="@drawable/aacizgi"
                 android:visibility="visible"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"/>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnAlan"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/btnCizgi"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:background="@drawable/aaalan"
                 android:visibility="visible"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"/>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnDuzenle"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/btnAlan"
                 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:background="@drawable/aaduzenle"
                 android:visibility="visible"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"/>
             
             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnSec"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/btnDuzenle"
                 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/aasec"
                 android:visibility="visible"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"/>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnKaydir"
                 android:layout_width="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_height="6.5mm"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/btnSec"
                 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:background="@drawable/aakaydir"
                 android:visibility="visible"
                 android:onClick="CizimAraclariDegistir"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.LiderBilgisayarYazilim.cepmap.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/abc_search_url_text_selected"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
    android:listSelector="@drawable/item_secici"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay"/>
```

and my java files

```
if ((Calendar.getInstance().getTime().after(asd.getTime())) | IkinciLisansKontrol()) {
    if (haritam.getUrl().contains("http"))
        return;
    haritam.loadUrl(getString(R.string.javascript) + getString(R.string.SJlisans1));
                        
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.SMLisansSuresi);
    actionBaslik.setText(R.string.SMLisansSuresi);
    BenimActionbar();
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAlan)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCizgi)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDuzenle)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnKaydir)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNavigator)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNokta)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSec)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    haritam.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
} else
    haritam.loadUrl(getString(R.string.javascript) + getString(R.string.SJlisans));
```

I want to use visible menu.

Although I have reviewed all the resources and examples on the internet for an average week, I still have not found a solution.

I dont know why errors this function
I think problem is here I am use android Studio 4.0.1
I am very happy if someone are fix the problem

Comment: after checking your image at the bottom , sounds like you have a null pointer exception with webview , can you show the code for implementing the webview

Comment: hi bruno https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ul8p5iBWRTeMIfrNqAU3Erl-t6eva-az?usp=sharing it'S complate the code thanks halping :)